# Renormalization in $\phi^3 + \phi^4$ theory in $D=4$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities

While reading notes on renormalization, specifically one-loop renormalization of $\phi^4 +\phi^3$ theory (Real Scalar Field) in $D=4$, In the section about corrections to coupling constants. For the mass, the $\lambda_4$ and $\lambda_3^2$ diagrams were considered. For $\lambda_3$ correction, the bubble diagram with $\lambda_3 \lambda_4$ was considered and for $\lambda_4$, the bubble diagram with $\lambda_4^2$ was considered. But why weren't the triangle diagram($\lambda_3^3$) and box diagram ($\lambda_3^4$) were considered for $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ respectively? Is it because they are UV finite or because only the lowest order correction was considered. (Mass can have two correction diagrams, one from each interaction). Even if they are UV finite, why won't they be considered for the correction of the coupling constants?

Comment: I could be wrong, my impression though is that the triangle diagram dimensionally scales as $p^{d - 6}$ ($d$-dimensional loop integral, 3 scalar propagators), and the box diagram scales as $p^{d-8}$, so both look UV-finite. If you are working in a $MS$ type scheme then, where you only subtract UV-divergent pieces, you don't need to worry about these diagrams

Comment: @JoshuaLin Yes, I am working in the $\bar{MS}$ scheme. Is it correct to say that the renormalization counter terms are made for only those UV divergent terms and we don't consider the UV finite terms as they don't really need counter terms? But terms of all order, as long as they are divergent should be normalized (in any theory)?